# Django can't resolve a url name

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I'm a newb of Django.

The code doesn't seem to be able to resolve my "login" url, and I require your aid to continue on with my development.

The following is the exception I get:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:9999/bz/logout/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 3.4.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bz')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\dev\python\eli\bz\views.py" in user_logout
  102.     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'), {'logged_out_success_message': user.username + " logged out successfully"})
File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  546.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  463.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /bz/logout/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from bz import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', views.index),
  url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
  (r'^logout/$', views.user_logout),
  (r'^register/$', views.register),
  )
```

And this is the problematic section where the resolution fails:

```
def user_logout(request):
  user = request.user
  if user.is_authenticated:
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'), {'logged_out_success_message': user.username + " logged out successfully"})
  else:
    return render(request, 'bz/index.html', {})
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well guys, found the problem.
when using "reverse" I forgot to add the app's name.
So the following did the trick.

Instead of:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'), {'logged_out_success_message': user.username + " logged out successfully"})
```

I wrote (adding 'bz:' as a prefix):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bz:login'), {'logged_out_success_message': user.username + " logged out successfully"})
```

And now it works.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason for writing your own login and logout functions? You could easily use the decorator ``@login_required`` and include in your urls.py the patterns from django.contrib.auth.views.

Comment: Well, since I'm using an extended USerProfile model, User login is enough, because the existence of a user and its successful login does not automatically validate whether said user is also associated to a UserProfile.